# Background colour and Background Images not showing in print to PDF in IE and Mozilla Firefox

Tags: html, css, asp.net, internet-explorer, firefox

I am trying to print a page. In that page, I have given a div a background color and background image.

When I view the print preview in chrome its work properly but in Firefox and
IE not showing background color and background image.

I used Print to PDF extension for Firefox and For IE used Win2PDF

I tried the following property for Chrome and display correctly:

-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;

but it's not showing for firefox and IE.

Any idea what might have gone wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check mozilla appearance settings
Open File->Page Setup and verify that "Print Background" is off. in mozilla

Use as the following html:


Red Background

Try these combinations